# SQL Server: single quote works in one environment but not in the other one

Tags: sql-server-2008

I built a single stored procedure like this:

```
create proc sp_test
  (@name nvarchar(100))
as
begin
    select * from company
    where company.companyname like '%'+@name+'%'
end
go
```

Now I want to test my stored procedure. Because the company name might have a single quote, such as: Bob's Warehouse, I use this name as a parameter to run my stored procedure in different environments like DEV, SIT, UAT. I replace single quotes with 2 single quotes. I found I can get results in DEV, but not in UAT. I don't know why.

```
exec sp_test 'Bob''s Warehouse'
```

Is this anything about database settings in the different environment? Why does the exact same code work in one environment but not the other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably nothing to do with the quote. Different data? different collations (e.g. case sensitivity)?

Comment: you might want to read about Set quoted_identifier in BOL

Comment: I check the collation is same.

Comment: Is the data the same? Does the UAT database contain a record for `Bob's Warehouse`?

Comment: This is just a very simple example to explain why it doesn't work. In the real world, whenever the input parameter has value with single quote, the related records won't be retrieved. So I don't think it's about case sensitivity issue, because all those parameters value are coming from table.

Comment: If all the parameters are coming from a table, have you validated that the parameters are exactly the same between environments?

Comment: executed the sproc supplying the WITH RECOMPILE option:

EXEC sp_test 'Bob''s Warehouse' WITH RECOMPILE
This tells SQL Server to throw away the existing query plan and build another one--but only this once.

You can also add the WITH RECOMPILE directly to the stored procedure right before the AS keyword. This tells SQL Server to throw out the query plan on every execution of the sproc

Answer (score 0):

If it is just because of single quote, it doesn't make sense working on one environment not another. Try to backup and restore the same data on different environment and give it a try, this probably is because of dirty data. If you have specific record like [Bob's Warehouse] doesn't work on different environment, try to check if the single quote you see is really char(39). You can also try run [exec sp_test 'Bob' + char(39) + 's Warehouse' ] on different environment see if it works.